Highcharts –– 3D stacked column, multi series
This question is about Highcharts 3D columns, described here:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/3d-column-stacking-grouping
I want to show three series with 3D columns, series behind each other (z axis) so that the front columns are a stack of 2 series.
I can do stacked but columns are on x axis:


Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 10,
            beta: 20,
            depth: 500,
            viewDistance: 5,
    }
        
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }

    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Community Tariff A',
    data: [21, 33, 27, 30, 30],
    stack: 'Billed'
  },{
        name: 'Community Tariff B',
    data: [64, 62, 51, 42, 35],
    stack: 'Billed' 
    },{
        name: 'Subsidized Tariff',
    data: [115, 125, 105, 99, 90],
    stack: 'Alternative1'
  }, {
      name: 'Regular Tariff',
    data: [145, 165, 135, 128, 116],
    stack: 'Alternative2'
  }
  ]
});
#container {
  height: 480px;
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>



https://jsfiddle.net/yfohmagd/
Or columns are on z axis but not stacked:


const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 10,
      beta: 20,
      depth: 500,
      viewDistance: 5,
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'May'],
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        column: {
      stacking: 'normal'
      },
      groupZPadding: 10,
      depth: 100,
      groupPadding: 0,
      grouping: false,
      },
  },
  yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'EUR',
            skew3d: true,
            style: {
                fontSize: '16px'
            }
        }
  },
  series: [{
        name: 'Community Tariff A',
    data: [21, 33, 27, 30, 30],
    stack: 'Billed'
  },{
        name: 'Community Tariff B',
    data: [64, 62, 51, 42, 35],
    stack: 'Billed' 
    },{
        name: 'Subsidized Tariff',
    data: [115, 125, 105, 99, 90],
    stack: 'Alternative1'
  }, {
      name: 'Regular Tariff',
    data: [145, 165, 135, 128, 116],
    stack: 'Alternative2'
  }
  ]
});
#container {
  height: 480px;
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>



https://jsfiddle.net/wc0o27rt/1/
How do I combine them? Thank you!

Hi @JC-, Unfortunately, this feature is currently not supported in Highcharts 3d-column series. Here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose you can create a bug report or a feature request.
